# Mouse scroll affects underlying map instead of leaflet custom control

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

I have created a custom control in leaflet. When using **scroll** or **click** on it, it **affects the underlying map** instead of the control.

```
        <CustomMapControl>
          <div
            className="custom-control"
            onScroll={(e) => e.stopPropagation()}
          >
            <div>
              {"Using scroll here, makes underlying map zoom in and zoom out"}
            </div>
          </div>
        </CustomMapControl>
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/basic-usage-with-react-leaflet-v3-forked-mqslin?file=/src/index.tsx)

I have tried using `stopPropagation()` but doesnt work.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve it using a `addEventListener` function instead of the `onScroll` method:

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    const onMouseWheel = e => e.stopPropagation()

    if (controlContainerRef.current) {
      controlContainerRef.current.addEventListener("mousewheel", onMouseWheel)
    }
    return () => {
      if (controlContainerRef.current) {
        controlContainerRef.current.removeEventListener("mousewheel", onMouseWheel)
      }
    };
  }, [controlContainerRef])
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/basic-usage-with-react-leaflet-v3-forked-mqslin?file=/src/index.tsx)